# Properties of composition f(g(x)) for g non-increasing and f convex

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

There are several questions on this site about combinations with convex and other types of functions. However, I believe the combination I am interested in has not been addressed.
Say that $g : \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ is a non-increasing function, and $f$ is a convex function. Then does $h(x) = f(g(x))$ have nice properties? In particular, does it have the quasiconvexity property? This would mean $h( (1-t)x_1 + t x_2) \leq \max\{ h(x_1) , h(x_2) \}$

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you might consider the cases when (i) $f$ has no global min, (ii) $f$ has a global min $x^*$.  Then examine monotonicity over intervals or subintervals. For example, can you show that if $f$ has no global min, then $f(g(x))$ is either nondecreasing or nonincreasing?